# Comparing BinarySearchTree nodes of type Integer

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

How can i compare 2 Tree nodes of type Integer in my data structure? If i use == it gives NullPointerException error for values greater than 128...

```
public int brElNaPutanji(BNode<Integer> tekuci, BNode<Integer> kraj){
    if (tekuci == kraj) 
        return 0;
    int trt = kraj.info;
    int prt = tekuci.info;
    if (trt < prt)
        return 1 + brElNaPutanji(tekuci.left, kraj);
    else
        return 1 + brElNaPutanji(tekuci.right, kraj);
}
```

And here is the BNode class

```
class BNode<E extends Comparable<E>> {

public E info;
public BNode<E> left;
public BNode<E> right;

public BNode(E info) {
    this.info = info;
    left = null;
    right = null;
}

public BNode(E info, BNode<E> left, BNode<E> right) {
    this.info = info;
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
}

}
```

Comment: `return 1 + brElNaPutanji(tekuci.left, kraj);` what happens if `left` is null?

Comment: It can never be null actually, this method counts the number of nodes from the root, up the node we want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `number1.equals(number2)` instead of `==` as `==` only checks if they are in the same memory area ,may not always be correct .

Comment: How does this address the NullPointerException?

Comment: Okay i solved the mystery, it is in other method which calculate's the height of the given node. Thanks for the helpful answer's anyway :)